# Do not apply certain CSS class styles to specific class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to not apply certain CSS classes to a particular class or id? I have an image in a grid using the Materialize CSS framework. I would like it to break outside the grid and reach the corners of the screen. Essentially I want to exclude the `.container`, `.row`, and the `.col` css styles from a class called `.break-grid`. However, I would still like other styles to apply. (in this case `.parallax-container` and `.parallax`.

Is there a better way to go about "breaking out of the grid" than the way I'm pursing? A pure CSS/HTML solution would be preferred but I am willing to use Javascript/Jquery to solve this as well.

Here is a code sample of what I'm trying to do. I have no CSS as this is a css framework (I do not want to edit the framework). I would need css to fix change it I presume.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <!-- Apply here -->
      <h1>Things</h1>
      <!-- Don't apply here -->
      <div class="parallax-container break-grid">
        <div class="parallax">
          <%= image_tag('infos/home/test_parallax.jpg')%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Apply here -->
      <h2>Stuff</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: Looks like you have access to the code, so just change `class="parallax-container break-grid"` to your own `class`. For example, `class="parallax-container my-grid"`.

Comment: What does "Is there a way to not apply certain CSS classes to a particular class" even mean? That's... literally what CSS classes are? You define a CSS `.whatever` block of rules, and then that gets applied to whichever element uses `whatever` as one of its classes. If you don't want to apply it, don't have it in the element's class list?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans By have the class `.break-grid` nested inside of `.container` for instance, `.break-grid` gets `.container`'s styles. I want to know how to exclude a nested element from getting that style without moving it out of the nesting.

Comment: you're working with _cascading stylesheets_, the "cascading" part is kind of literally the whole point, so you don't get to "not inherit" styles. Instead of thinking in terms of "not inheriting parent styles", think "what needs to be set": just explicitly set each rule that you explicitly need for your element, and that will override what you inherit.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I realize that, however, I'm using a CSS framework which means that these parent classes are black-boxed to me. I realize I can open up the css files for the framework, but that defeats the purpose of a framework in the first place - if I start poking around in implementation details. Additionally, I highly doubt it's just one or two things that constrain the grid, but a whole host of things making the solution brittle to framework updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` CSS pseudo-class. [( On MDN )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
  .container > .row > .col > *:not(.parallax-container) { 
    //styling
  }
```

**Note**: realize this is a demonstration, I'm not going through every BootStrap property that would be applied innately, and you would have to do that yourself:

```css
.container > .row > .col > *:not(.parallax-container)  {
 background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <h1>Things</h1>
     
     // Do not apply here
      <div class="parallax-container break-grid">
        <div class="parallax">
          <span>whatever</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      

      <h2>Stuff</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Personally, I would advise you to listen to everyone else and just build this thing using Cascading styles. `:not` is an excellent tool, but I get the impression that you're likely to abuse it/over-rely on it and get yourself in a bind style-wise.

In any case, good luck!